# Is ext4 stable on 11.10?

Tags: filesystem, ext4, ext3

I have seen that Ubuntu 11.10 is offering Ext4 as default file system. As I have googled some time on ext4 and found that ext3 is quite stable that ext4 as it still has some bugs.

Even the Ubuntu Documentation is referring Ext3. [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/installation-guide/i386/apcs03.html)

So, I would like to know whether Ext4 is currently stable on 11.10 or not than Ext3

Answer (score 1):

Ext4 has been around for some years now and I have never had problems with it even if the power was "accidentally" gone. The page that you have linked has not changed since at least 2010 (it's essentially a duplicate of https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/apcs03.html).

As far as I know, Ext4 has been the default filesystem since 9.10 Karmic. If it was unstable, we would have known it now.

Comment: I've noticed there are generally a lot of outdated webpages about Linux in general... for example, I think some Ubuntu webpages recommend doubling the amount of RAM to get your swap partition size, but this is from the old days when 1GB was a lot.  It'd be ludicrous to make a swap of 16GB because you have 8GB of RAM!

Comment: Not just Linux, but because of the fast development information becomes quickly outdated. Especially with the bunch of blogs that are giving some commands or a short text without further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

no man ext4 file system is so stable and ubuntu 11.10 choose it by default so it's better than old file systems

btfrs file system is the future but still need develop i try before to choose it and install old version of ubuntu but it didn't work